# Testing if the user input value is in a given array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I just created a five rounds rock-paper-scissors game using vanilla JavaScript. The program runs just fine so far except for the fact every time I start the game for the very first time it will take any user input as invalid no matter what and won't count that round.

This is my code:

```js
// Global variables
let playerWins = 0;
let computerWins = 0;
let array = [];
let validInput = 0;
let newRound = "";

// This function generates a computer selection
const computerPlay = () => {
    array = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

// This function stores player selection
const playerSelection = (selection) => {
    selection = prompt("Enter: 'Rock', 'Paper' or 'Scissors'").toLowerCase();
    validInput = array.indexOf(selection);
    console.log(validInput);
    
    // This loop will validate user input is correct
    while (validInput === -1) {
        alert("Invalid input, try again");
        selection = prompt("Enter 'Rock', 'Paper' or 'Scissors'").toLowerCase();
        validInput = array.includes(selection);
    }
    return selection;
}

// This function plays a single round of Rock-Paper-Scissors
const playRound = (playerSelection, computerPlay) => {

    // If both players select the same item
    if (playerSelection === computerPlay) {
        return alert("It's a tie!");
    }

    // If player selects "Rock"
    if (playerSelection === "rock") {
        if (computerPlay === "scissors") {
            playerWins += 1;
            return alert("Rock crushes scissors: YOU WIN!!!");
        } else {
            computerWins += 1;
            return alert("Paper covers rock: YOU LOOSE!!!");
        }
    }

    // If player selects "Paper"
    if (playerSelection === "paper") {
        if (computerPlay === "rock") {
            playerWins += 1;
            return alert("Paper covers rock: YOU WIN!!!");
        } else {
            computerWins += 1;
            return alert("Scissors cuts paper: YOU LOOSE!!!");
        }
    }

    // If player selects "Scissors"
    if (playerSelection === "scissors") {
        if (computerPlay === "rock") {
            computerWins += 1;
            return alert("Rock crushes scissors: YOU LOOSE!!!");
        } else {
            playerWins += 1;
            return alert("Scissors cuts paper: YOU WIN!!!");
        }
    }
}

// This function keeps score and reports a winner or loser at the end
const trackWins = (pw, cw) => {
    alert("COMPUTER WINS: " + cw + "\nPLAYER WINS: " + pw)
    if (pw > cw) {
        alert("YOU WIN THIS ROUND, CONGRAX!!!")
    } else if (cw > pw) {
        alert("YOU LOOSE THIS ROUND, SO BEST LUCK FOR THE NEXT TIME :_(")
    } else {
        alert("IT'S A TIE")
    }
}

// This function creates a 5 round game
const game = () => {   
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        playRound(playerSelection(), computerPlay());
    }
    trackWins(playerWins, computerWins);
}

do {
    game();
    newRound = prompt("Do yo want to play another round? Type 'y' to continue or any other key to exit").toLowerCase();
    
} while (newRound === "y");
alert("It was a good game, bye for now!")
```

I will appreciate any ideas to fix this problem or improve my script, thank you in advance!

Comment: `validInput = array.indexOf(selection);` at this point, your array variable is still [] becuase `computerPlay()` (that sets the array values) is called after `playerSelection()`

Comment: also your while loop in `playerSelection` will not loop at all (it runs only once even if selection is wrong again), because `array.includes()` returns boolean value and you compare it to -1.

Comment: I totally get it now @user3743266 I just populated my array variable at the beginning and the problem is gone, thank you great wise man.

Comment: I was testing with includes() and indexfOf() it happened that I forgot to change back to indexfOf() before posting, thank you @rsm

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code can be simplified to better reflect question - say, you have an array, and a variable that stores user input. How do you test if the input value is in the array?

```
var arr=['Rock','Paper','Scissors'];
var inp='Rock'; //user input
```

You could use a while loop, but there's a much faster way:

```
var options={'rock':0,'paper':1,'scissors':2}
var inp='Rock'; //user input
var ninp=inp.toLowerCase().trim(); //normalize input

var pick=(options[ninp]);

if (pick==null) // invalid selection
if (pick==0) //rock
if (pick==1) //paper
if (pick==2) //scissors
```

The code can be further cleaned up with a switch:

```
switch (pick){
  case 0: ... break; //rock
  case 1: ... break; //paper
  case 2: ... break; //scissors
  default: //invalid
}
```

Comment: I think you are right @Schien. Title is already changed. I also implemented some changes in my script based on you suggestions, thank you!